# couldn't find key MYSQL_KEY in Secret default/mysql-secret

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, deployment, kubernetes-secrets, skaffold

I have the following file that creates a `mysql-secret` for `mysql` deployment pod.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysql-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  mysql-password: MTExMTEx
  mysql-root-password: MTExMTEx
  mysql-user: YQ==
```

The problem is that, previously I could deploy `mysql` on `Kubernetes` cluster using the secret key created by this command:

```
kubectl create secret generic mysql-secret --from-literal MYSQL_KEY=11111
```

And using `MYSQL_KEY` I could pass it to other `deployment` files like `auth` as you can see below:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: auth-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: auth
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: auth
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: auth
          image: auth
          env:
            - name: MYSQL_URI
              value: 'mysql://auth-mysql-srv:3306/users_auth'
            - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mysql-secret
                  key: MYSQL_KEY
```

But now I don't have a key using a `yaml` file to create the secret key and I get the following error because of that:

```
 - deployment/auth-mysql-depl is ready. [3/5 deployment(s) still pending]
 - deployment/mysql: container mysql in error: &ContainerStateWaiting{Reason:CreateContainerConfigError,Message:couldn't find key MYSQL_KEY in Secret default/mysql-secret,}
    - pod/mysql-78bbf5f6f4-vbpkz: container mysql in error: &ContainerStateWaiting{Reason:CreateContainerConfigError,Message:couldn't find key MYSQL_KEY in Secret default/mysql-secret,}
```

How can I add a `key: MY_SQL` property to the `secret.yaml` file or find a way to eliminate it from the other `deployment` files like `auth` that uses it?

If I just eliminate `key: MYSQL_KEY` from auth `deployment` file I get this error:

```
 - The Deployment "auth-depl" is invalid: spec.template.spec.containers[0].env[1].valueFrom.secretKeyRef.key: Required value
```

EDIT: I tried to create the secret before I run `skaffold dev` using `kubectl apply -f mysql-secret.yaml` command and it worked. My question is, how can I say to `skafoold` please run `kubectl apply -f` on `mysql-secret.yaml` file before the other `yaml` files?

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v4beta1
kind: Config
build:
  artifacts:
  - image: auth
    context: auth-service
    sync:
      manual:
      - src: src/**/*.ts
        dest: .
    docker:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
  - image: client
    context: client-service
    sync:
      manual:
      - src: lib/**/*.dart
        dest: .
    docker:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
  local:
    push: false
manifests:
  rawYaml:
  - ./infra/k8s/*
deploy:
  kubectl: {}
  kubeContext: kind-kind
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the deployment file is correct but your secret does not have the required keys. the keys are case sensitive. In your secret.yaml file I do not see `MYSQL_KEY`. Edit the file and add the key.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysql-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  mysql-password: MTExMTEx
  mysql-root-password: MTExMTEx
  mysql-user: YQ==
  MYSQL_KEY: MTExMTEx
```

*please note value of MYSQL_KEY in the above snippet is random. it should be base64 string of actual value*

then run kubectl apply -f . *Off course, Kubectl tool should be installed and should point to the correct cluster.*

if this command runs well, your pods will be up in a few minutes.

Another way to edit the secret directly is to run `kubectl edit secret secret-name` or `kubectl patch`  command. By this way you can edit k8s objects directly.

Comment: Thank you, it seems it solved my previous problem, but I don't know why do I still get `- deployment/auth-depl: container auth in error: &ContainerStateWaiting{Reason:CreateContainerConfigError,Message:secret "mysql-secret" not found,}
    - pod/auth-depl-8659c55b76-nbfl7: container auth in error: &ContainerStateWaiting{Reason:CreateContainerConfigError,Message:secret "mysql-secret" not found,}`

Comment: try to remove the pod, and check secret is created properly. if things still not work may be your cluster admin added some security checks (I don't belive though) please consider rating / accepting this answer

Comment: it clearly says secret not found, are you creating a secret and deployment in the same namespace? check spellings it is case sensitive

Comment: I do all in the same namespace. Actually I have created a Skaffold.yaml file and it does the job.

Comment: I can create the secret via `kubectl create secret generic mysql-secret --from-literal MYSQL_KEY=11111` command.

Comment: I found the problem. Please read the `EDIT` part I added to my question.

Comment: great you found answer on your own :)

Answer (score 0):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysql-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  mysql-password: MTExMTEx
  mysql-root-password: MTExMTEx
  mysql-user: YQ==
```

In this MYSQL_KEY is missing under data.

The mapping goes like this

```
  env:
    - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD //The name that you used in ur properties
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: mysql-secret    //The name that you used under  metadata: name: in your secret file
          key: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD //The key of key-value pair under data: in your secretfile,
```